# Typescript error on reduce array function - "string' is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am currently learning typescript and have run into a typescript error from the following function:

```
export interface WebspaceBackupArtifact {
    readonly date?: string;
    readonly name?: string | null;
    readonly path?: string | null;
    readonly type?: string | null;
}
 
interface WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended extends WebspaceBackupArtifact {
  size: string;
  type: string;
}

const selected = [] as WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended[],

const totalSize = (): number => {
return selected
        .filter(
          (artifact: WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended) =>
            artifact.type !== 'directory',
        )
        .reduce(
          (accumulator: number, artifact: WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended) =>
            accumulator + artifact.size,
          0,
        );
}
```

The above function produces the following errors:

> ERROR in /app/src/views/myfile.vue(394,11): No overload matches this
> call. Overload 1 of 3, '(callbackfn: (previousValue:
> WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended, currentValue:
> WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended, currentIndex: number, array:
> WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended[]) => WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended,
> initialValue: WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended):
> WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended', gave the following error. my-project
> |     Argument of type '(accumulator: number, artifact:
> WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended) => string' is not assignable to
> parameter of type '(previousValue: WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended,
> currentValue: WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended, currentIndex: number,
> array: WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended[]) =>
> WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended'. my-project    |       Types of
> parameters 'accumulator' and 'previousValue' are incompatible.
> my-project    |         Type 'WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended' is not
> assignable to type 'number'.

and

> my-project    |   Overload 2 of 3, '(callbackfn: (previousValue:
> number, currentValue: WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended, currentIndex:
> number, array: WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended[]) => number,
> initialValue: number): number', gave the following error. my-project
> |     Argument of type '(accumulator: number, artifact:
> WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended) => string' is not assignable to
> parameter of type '(previousValue: number, currentValue:
> WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended, currentIndex: number, array:
> WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended[]) => number'. my-project    |
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'. my-project    |
> 392 |         ) my-project    |     393 |         .reduce( my-project
> |   > 394 |           (accumulator: number, artifact:
> WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended) => my-project    |         |
> ^ my-project    |     395 |             accumulator + artifact.size,
> my-project    |     396 |           0, my-project    |     397 |
> );

Why would it be throwing these errors after I have defined the types? I tried changing this line:

`(accumulator: number, artifact: WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended) =>`

to

`(previousValue: WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended, currentValue: WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended) =>`

but it still resulted in the same error message...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended.size` as `number` therefore `accumulator + artifact.size` returns a string. Changing the definition of `size` to `number` fixes the error.